# A question regarding registration form, social login and checkboxes

Tags: website-design, login, social, terms-of-service, register

I am a frontend/backend developer. Recently I was provided a design from our UX dev for a registration form for a website. It looks something like this:

------------------------------------|

**[  Login with Google   ]**

**[ Login with Facebook ]**

------------or------------

`Enter Name`

`Enter Email`

`Enter password`

`Confirm password`

`✔` Subscribe to Newsletter

`✔` Accept terms & conditions

**[ Register ]**

------------------------------------|

The social login buttons are on top of the form because that's what most users prefer to use, so its more focused.

The social login buttons act as both login and registration - if the user exists, they're logged in. If not, an account is created for them and they're logged in.

The problem is that the `subscribe` and `accept` checkboxes are tied only to the login form, so registering with google or facebook means those form inputs are not submitted. Even if I did make them submit, since they're in different places, users won't feel like checking/unchecking them when registering with social account. On top of that, the social login buttons are also present on Login page, so if a non-registered user clicks these button from Login page, their account is created automatically even though they never checked the `accept` button.

For now, I have put another `accept` button below the `Login with Facebook` button so that to login/register with social account they have to check that one instead of the one below. It now looks like this:

------------------------------------|

**[  Login with Google   ]**

**[ Login with Facebook ]**

`✔` Accept terms & conditions

------------or------------

`Enter Name`

`Enter Email`

`Enter password`

`Confirm password`

`✔` Subscribe to Newsletter

`✔` Accept terms & conditions

**[ Register ]**

------------------------------------|

The problem with this approach is that

1. There will be 2 `accept` check boxes in the register form.
2. Users registering with social logins will not be able to use `subscribe` checkbox, I could put one checkbox more below social login but it would be too noisy.
3. I don't want to show it on login page, but since users can register from login page as well, I have to put them?

Can you guys provide me with a better solution? I talked to my UX designer about this, he said he had never come across this issue .

Answer (score 1):

**Separate the login and the sign up form**

IMO it is weird that the login/sign up is the same form for social logins. As a user I would be confused as to why I always have to accept the terms&conditions each time I log into the website with google/facebook.

Other websites (such as trello or linkedin) separate the login and sign up forms. This makes it way clearer what you need to check and what is happening.

Also note where the "Terms of Service" label ("By signing up you...") is placed in the sign up form. That's where I would also place the Newsletter checkbox.

[image: sign up and login form for trello]

Comment: We do have it just like this, separate login and register pages with social login on both.

Although in trello's case, if I signed up with google, I had to accept the terms after google authentication. 

It's one more step, but maybe for the best.